# Converter fracao de hora no formato hh:mm:ss

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

Meu conjunto de dados de horarios esta armazenado na variavel time = [0., 0.08333333,   0.16666667,   0.25, 0.33333333, 0.41666667, 0.5 , 0.58333333,  0.66666667,  0.75,   0.83333333,   0.91666667, 1. , 08333333, 1.16666667]

Alguem sabe me dizer se existe uma maneira simples de converter isso no formato hh:mm:ss?

Eu tentei criar uma funcao, mas esta dando erro:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

def time2dt(time):

    seconds = int(time*60*60)
    minutes, seconds = int(divmod(seconds, 60))
    hours, minutes = int(divmod(minutes, 60))
    return dt.datetime(hours, minutes, seconds) + dt.timedelta(time % 1)

    dates   = [time2dt(time[i]) for i in np.arange(len(time))]
    datestr = [i.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for i in dates]
```

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: Fazendo isso, aparece um outro erro: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'time'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro está acontecendo por que  o `divmod` que você está chamando não devolve um número - para ter um resto de divisão em Python, use simplesmente o operador `%` . Divmod devolve a parte inteira e o resto da divisão - mas não é por isso que todas as outras funçoes (o "int" em particular) vai poder trabalhar automaticamente com uma sequência.

Faça o programa por partes, sem esperar que a linguagem seja "mágica" (por que ela não é, ela é bem racional), e você vai ter o resultado esperado - mais pra frente, conforme você tiver mais desenvoltura, pode se preocupar em querer encurtar as linhas de código:

```
minutes = time // 60
seconds = time % 60
```

em vez do incorreto `minutes, seconds = int(divmod(time, 60))` que você tem aí.

(o  `//` é o operador de divisão "inteira" que trunca o resultado).

Além disso, outro problema que você tem mais pra baixo é tentar criar um datetime.datetime passando apenas horas, minutos e segundos: datetimes precisam do dia, mes e ano.  - crie um objeto `datetime.time` com dia, mes e ano, e depois sim, combine como desejar com outros objetos.

E por fim, não diretamente relacionado com seu problema - mas você não deveria mais estar usando Python 2.7 - em menos de dois anos essa versão estará completamente sem suporte de nenhum tipo - faz quase 10 anos que foi lançada. As versões 3.x do python são as atuais e tem várias facilidades e novas funcionalidades.

Comment: Obrigada! Eu fiz umas alteracoes aqui, e agora esta funcionando...quanto ao uso do python, eu estava usando a versao 3.6, mas tive problemas, travava com frequencia e por isso acabei voltando pra versao mais antiga mas com certeza, em algum momento, acabarei voltando a ela novamente